# What is the correct duration of every yuga?

Tags: scripture, yuga

There are different duration for the major 4 yuga (Sat, Tretaa, Dvaapara, Kali) found in internet. With recent (one of the) study it is believed that Ramayana happend 7k years back and Mahabharata 5k years back.

Most of the internet sites suggest lacs(100k) of years for various yugas, but that's not convincing with above study and also sidelines the theory of human evolution, ice age etc.

Any logical clarification on that?

Comment: Good question sir! IMHO There's no way to know which is correct. Scriptures have been modified several times over the years, there is no denying the fact. THat's why the saints place less emphasis on factual details and more emphasis on self-realization. We cannot be sure whether Ramayana happened 12000 or 15000 years back or not. But we can be sure that the lessons taught by Rama are very real and applicable to the World even today. :) All the best!!

Comment: Studies are either based on the Archaeological facts or by reading texts very carefully. I think we hardly have any of the things that surely belongs to Ramayan/Mahabharat age. Regarding reading texts very carefully, researchers basically points out things saying that this thing started in this year or that year and taking into account all such considerations, draft a date for which it could belong, eg, for a mention of usage of gold coins, they can research the first occurrence reported for such coins. Similarly summing all other facts from different parts of the world, they decide a period.

Comment: So, we can't be really sure about their findings because if one thing is not found anywhere else doesn't mean that it doesn't exist. Also, a fact to be noted is that texts are rewritten by different people in their own perspective, so main story being same but other things mentioned may relate to what is prevalent in that era when it was rewritten and this is what is caught by people who date them. Archeology can still prove better but most of the things are have either been destroyed by time or are submerged deep beneath sea or land. So until, they are found we can't be sure.

Answer (score 2):

**Astrology and DoomsDay**

Time between Sunrise to another sunrise is known as Savan DAY. Time taken by sun to complete one degree of zodiac is known as `solar day- saur dina`. Time taken between one star rise to another is known as `Nakshatra dina`. Time taken to complete one tithi is known as `Lunar day-Chandra dina`.

So ,when will be the dooms day? According to **Jyotish Shastra** ,  a day is a `savan day`. There are 365/15/30/22/30 days in a solar year. A savan year is 360 days only. Such 360 days constitute one day for the `Devatas in Swarga`.

```
hence 360X360=1 Devamana Year;
1000 such devmana years is the span of kaliyuga;
2000 years (devamana) is Dwapara yuga;
3000 years make              Tretayuga ;
4000 years make               Kritayuga;
each yuga has a sandhi period.As one yuga ends abrubtly another yuga does not take
over .
There is smooth transition of yuga effects from one to another through transition
period(sandhi) of 1/10 th of each yuga. ie kaliyuga is preceded and succeded by
1/10th of 1000 years ie 100 years before and after kaliyuga. similarly dwapar is                        
preceded by 200 years etc.

kritayuga is  4800 years = 4800X360 =1728000 human years.
Tretayuga is 3600 years = 3600X360 =1296000 human years.
Dwapara  is  2400years = 2400X360 =  864000 human years.
Kaliyuga   is  1200 years = 1200X360 = 432000 human years.
```

And

```
One Mahayuga is the cycle of four yugas 12000X360 = 4320000 human years .
1000 + 1000 mahayugas equals a day and a night for Bramha in BramhaLoka.
There are 14 Manus in one Bramha day .
Each Manu lives for  308571428.57142857142857142857143 human years. This is known as 
Manvantara. There is a mini pralaya ( involving Swarga bhuvarloka and Bhuloka-  
BhurBhuvaSwa) in 308571428 . 57142857142857142857143 years .
```

This pralaya can be called as doomsday for humans on earth and heaven. But this is not the dooms day for the Universe.

Universe ends after BRAMHA COMPLETES 100 YEARS . ie

```
2000X 4320000X360 X100 = 311040000000000 human years .
```

of which BRAMHA has completed 50 years , in his fifty first year he is in his first day , completed 13 ghatikas ,42 palas.

we have still half way to go for a dooms day. In his morning of next half , we have completed 6 Manvantaras

```
This is seventh VAIVASVATA MANVANTARA .OF SEVENTY ONE MAHAYUGAS WE HAVE COMPLETED
TWENTY SEVEN MAHAYUGAS AND IN TWENTYEIGTH , WE HAVE FINISHED KRITA-TRETA-DWAPARA AND
IN KALIYUGA WE HAVE COMPLETED 5109 YEARS OUT OF 432000 YEARS. WE STILL HAVE 426891
YEARS TO GO BEFORE THIS KALIYUGA ENDS
```